# I can't understand a fragment in the Mass-Spectrum of Benzophenone

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

**Summary:**
Took multiple Mass spectra of Benzophenone; There always is a peak at $\pu{152.2}$ that I don't understand.

I made some Measurements of Benzophenone with a GC-MS. Always using EI (electron impact ionization). The spectra at an energy of $\pu{70eV}$ is pretty easy to interpret at first.
[image: GC-MS-spectrum of Benzophenone at an ionization-energy of 70eV]

However taking a closer look the peak at 152.2 doesn't make any sense to me. I see it as well in the spectra with other ionization energies.
[image: GC-MS-spectrum with 90eV]
[image: GC-MS-spectrum with 30eV]
The same peak also appears in spectra that can be found on the Internet. E.g. [Here](https://msbi.ipb-halle.de/MassBank/RecordDisplay?id=MSBNK-Fac_Eng_Univ_Tokyo-JP003533) or on [NIST](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C119619&Mask=200#Mass-Spec) and even in this [advert](https://www.shimadzu.com/an/sites/shimadzu.com.an/files/pim/pim_document_file/applications/posters/10465/sio219089.pdf).
I can't find to think of a reasonable explanation for this peak. A book of mine (1) tells me that the characteristic mass difference of Δm/z = 30 is typical for $\ce{H2C=O}$ fragments. However I like I said I can't explain how this would make any sense.

Can anyone clear this for me?

(1) Strukturanalytik organischer und anorganischer Verbindungen; M. Reichenbächer, J. Popp; Teubner Verlag, first edition; Wiesbaden 2007

Comment: Why reject the choice you mentioned that a CH2O fragment is removed resulting in (C6H4)2 biphenylene?

Comment: An argument in favor of the loss of a fragment $\ce{CH2O}$ is the rather low intensity of the resulting ion $152.2$, about $1-2$%. So this loss with production of biphenylene should be rare.

Comment: Another argument is the large 77.1 peak which I imagine as phenyl groups of some sort able to recombine with each other at low yield to form some mix of biphenyl at 154 and biphenylene at 152.